What are the meaning and function of -ne in superne and pone?
What are the meaning and function of -ne in superne and pone? Oxford Latin Dictionary seems to say that the senses of -ne is related to making questions, and it is hard for me to relate its senses there to the two examples mentioned at the beginning.

The OLD doesn't have entries for bound morphemes (parts of words, like the -ne in pone); the -ne it lists is a clitic, i.e. a separate word that is typically written attached to another word because it doesn't carry its own accent. There is no real reason to assume the morpheme -ne and the clitic -ne are related. (Also note that supernē ends in a long vowel, so it's not the same construction as pone.)

@Cairnarvon Leiden, in its entry for super, says "adv. superne probably contains the suffix *-ne (cf. pone < *postne)".
Besides, the downvotes don't make sense to me.

@Elederete L&S specifically have sŭpernē, i.e. as a regular adverb from supernus, but it looks like Lucretius does have a few clear instances of supernĕ, which is interesting.

@Cairnarvon Lewis is often outdated for etymology — thus not reliable —, just like Gaffiot. In Lucretius we also see īnfernĕ for infernus. For adverbs, the -e is short unless the adverb is taken from an adjetive (alte, belle). It is possible that supernus is back-derived from superne as Leiden says, and that later superne was reinterpreted as coming from supernus instead of otherwise, making people use a long e instead. However, it is strange that this would not have happened with inferne — as there is no infernē, just īnfernĕ.
